# Rolling Window Forecast

Tags: python, regression, rolling-computation, forecast, horizon

I want to predict exchange rates with macroeconomic fundamentals doing an out of sample forecast with time series data in Python.

To assess the forecast accuracy I want to apply a rolling window regression i.e. the number of consecutive observations per rolling window.
Dependent variable is the Eur/USD exchange rate and my (first) explanatory variable are interest rate differences between US and Europe. Timespan is 01/1999 till 01/2019.

Theoretically, one chooses the window size first, then the forecast horizon and evaluates the model with the RMSE.

But I'm not quite sure how to set up a rolling regression in Python.

I was struggling by using MovingOLS within the deprecated stats/ols module. 
So, I downloaded the Pyfinance package which includes Rolling Regression.

But how can I change the forecast horizon here to 3 months for instance? Are there other ways/packages to solve this problem?

Here is the code with respect to the Pyfinance Package:

```
rolling = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=X, window=228,) #window size equal to the length of my training set

rolling.beta.head()

rolling.ms_err.head()
rolling.ms_err
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target and predictor variables are pandas.Series or pandas.DataFrame objects:

```
model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=y, x=x, window_type='rolling', window=90)
prediction = model.y_predict
```

Change the window parameter to the number of days (assuming your data is daily)

Edit: `pd.stats` has been actually been deprecated in newer versions of pandas, this should be possible with `pandas.rolling_apply`, feeding in whichever OLS regression function you are using:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html